# regular expression: remove spaces from part of a line

Tags: regex, notepad++

I want to remove spaces from part of an expression.

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| Input | `some other stuff goes here, "alpha bravo charlie delta echo"` |
| Desired output | `some other stuff goes here, "alphabravocharliedeltaecho"` |

`, "alpha` is a constant on some lines after which I want all spaces removed.

I am currently working with

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| Find: | `^(.*, "alpha) (((\w*) )*)(\w*")$` |
| Replace with: | `$1|$2|$3|$4|$5|$6|$7|$8` (pipes and extra outputs to see what was happening) |
| Results | `some other stuff goes here, "alpha|bravo charlie delta |delta |delta|echo"|||` |
| Expected results | `some other stuff goes here, "alpha|bravo|charlie|delta|echo"|||` |

I tried variations of the regular expression, but haven't had better results yet.  Clearly, being unable to capture `bravo` and `charlie` separately, I'm not understanding how to capture every match.

(This seems like it would be a common question.  I understand if this is a duplicate, but I have been unable to find it.)

**Update:**

I have used the pattern below to get the job done, but I still want to understand this better to be able to do it in a single pass.

`(^.*, "alpha )(\w+) (.*)$` repeated until "Replace All: 0 occurrences were replaced in the entire file"
`(^.*, "alpha) (.*)$`

Comment: `(?:\G(?!^)|"alpha\b)\S*+\K\h+` should be enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?:"alpha|\G(?!^)\w+)\K\h+(?=.*?")`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?:             # non capture group
    "alpha          # literally
  |               # OR
    \G(?!^)         # restart from last match position, not at the beginning of line
    \w+             # 1 or more word character
)               # end group
\K              # forget all we have seen until this position
\h+             # 1 or more horizontal spaces
(?=.*?")        # positive lookahead, make sure we have a double quote after
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: As `"alpha` can exist before the comma, I had to change the expression to `(?:, "alpha|\G(?!^)\w+)\K\h+(?=.*?")`.  Thanks for the great explanation.

Comment: @dougp: You're welcome, glad it helps.